# Is it possible to call an external program from a regular MySQL setup?

Tags: mysql, call, external

Is it possible to call an external program from a regular MySQL setup? (and get it's output)

Something like this:

```
UPDATE users SET something = CALL('/path/program', 'params') WHERE id = 1;
```

I want to use as program parameter a value from the table, for example `users.name`.

Answer (score 0):

What about build the query with some shell command and run it in this way?

```
# build query
echo -n "UPDATE users SET something = '" > query.sql
echo -n `/path/your_command` >> query.sql
echo -n "' WHERE id = 1;" >> query.sql

# run it!
mysql db_name < query.sql
```

Comment: I want to use as parameter a value from the table.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom user defined function. [Here's a blog post](http://crazytechthoughts.blogspot.com/2011/12/call-external-program-from-mysql.html) about it.